# How to use IsLeaf in mondrian mdx formula?

Tags: function, mdx, pentaho, cube, mondrian

Trying to recreate this formula in Pentaho Mondrian Cube.

**iif(ISLEAF([Time].[Month].CurrentMember)),[Measures].m1,0)**

This formula is being used in SSAS cube already. Need to recreate similar formula in Pentaho Mondrian Cube.

Can IsLeaf be used in mondrian or is there any alternative for this?

Comment: i am not aware with SSAS. but what is your requirement?
if you want something like Example : Let's say i want sum of all the MALE's  then how i will right is :
SUM( [categorized].[MALE] , [Measures].[GENDER] ) in this Categorized is my dimention name.

Comment: @WorkingHard.. Thank you for your input.. My requirement is finding the value for measure m1 for the last node of dimension Month.. for example, there would be 12 months in selection.. so in the report the last row should show the value of m1 for the last month (12th month in this case).. how do I do it in Pentaho?

Comment: [Dim Month.columnname].[1] try this if it is working or not.

Comment: @Akira: For now it is hard to get why do you need IsLeaf function. Can you add some more info: What exactly do you mean by the last node: the last existing node in [Month] level or the farthest node in hierarchy? Do you want to use the expression as a calculated measure in your cube, or just use it in one particular query? If the latter, then it would be nice to know your query and levels of [Time] hierarchy. And in any case it is nice to see the expected output.

Comment: @user4637357 Thanks for the input.. We are using the expression in a calculated measure.. to elaborate more, consider calculating closing stock for a month.. we would like to show this value only once for the last row in the result set & not every row of the displayed report.. so we need to access the last row in the result set.. if it is last row then show the value otherwise set it to zero.. how can we do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should work at any arbitrary level within the default hierarchy.

It will return [Mesures].m1 for the last year, which (has non-empty m1 measure and satisfies your filter conditions) in case you select `[Time].[Year]` members.

Or it will return the measure for the last month of the last year, which has non-empty m1 measure in case you select `[Time].[Month]` members.

Though I don't think it will work if you mix members for different levels (e.g. `WITH SET time_members AS {[Time].[2017], [Time].[2017].[1]. [Time].[2017].[1].[31]}`)

If you don't need such a generic approach, then this solution may be simplified and the measure calculation speed may be improved.

**Warning: the query may cause 100% CPU utilization (or may not, I am not sure), thus making your server unresponsive. So, choose your testing environment carefully.**

*Disclaimer:* I don't have mondrian to test at the moment, so the following example is very likely to have errors.

```cs
Iif(
    // Check if current [Time] member is the last member:
    [Time].CurrentMember
    IS
    // Take the 0th member from the end of the set (AFAIK, mondrian sets are guaranteed to be ordered):
    Tail(
        // AFAIK, Level.Members returns the full set of members, disregarding query filters.
        // So I use Filter function to filter members, which don't exist in context of current cell.
        // It should leave only members, which (are related to current cell and satisfy filter conditions of the query).
        Filter(
            [Time].CurrentMember.Level.members
            // If your measure is nullable, then you might want to use count measure in this condition instead of m1:
            , NOT IsEmpty([Measures].m1)
        )
        // Number of members to get by the Tail() function:
        , 1
        // Return the only member of the set as a Member (not as a Set):
    ).Item(0)
    // return if true
    , [Measures].m1
    // else:
    , 0
)
```

Some points that may be problematic and need to be tested:

1. How the measure is calculated if the last [Time] member has empty m1
   measure (if this is a valid case for your measure)
2. How the measure is calculated at different levels of [Time]
   hierarchy.
3. How the measure is calculated if you don't use [Time] dimension in
   report explicitly.
4. How the measure is calculated if you use [Time] dimension on slicer
   axis only (in WHERE condition)
5. How the measure is calculated if you use restricted set of [Time]
   members, e.g. explicitly enumerating members in set literal (e.g.
   `{[Time].[2006].[01], [Time].[2006].[02]}`) or via using Filter()
   function on the dimension.
6. How the measure is calculated if you use fiters on other
   dimensions/measures.
7. How the measure is calculated at calculated members of [Time]
   dimension (including totals and sub-totals generated by Analyzer).
8. How the measure is calculated if you select members from different
   levels on the same axis.

Comment: Can you please review below query? This query is getting generated when I created an aggregation table named AggTable1 in Pentaho Aggregation designer. 

select
    `Dim_Time`.`Time_Id` as `c0`,
    `Dim_Time`.`month_no` as `c1`
from
    `Dim_Time` as `Dim_Time`
where
    `Dim_Time`.`Time_Id` = `AggTable1`.`Dim_Time_Month_(Key)`
group by
    `Dim_Time`.`Time_Id`,
    `Dim_Time`.`month_no`
order by
    ISNULL(`Dim_Time`.`Time_Id`) ASC, `Dim_Time`.`Time_Id` ASC

Why is AggTable1 table not getting selected in from clause?

Comment: Sorry, don't have much experience with aggregate tables. The only thing I can suggest is to check whether there are different tables with same alias - in this case one of the tables will not appear in from clause.